# is it possible to ORDER BY different table while checking 2 column for certain equations

Tags: php, mysql

So lets say i have 2 tables.

**table users:**

id | name | date

**table weight_tracking;**

id | user_id | previous_weight | current_weight | date

weight_tracking table is being updated daily with user current weight and previous_weight.

I am trying to display all users ordering by previous_weight - current_weight (so by the difference in weight - who ever lost the most weight will show up first)

Can that be done with 1 call ?

Comment: Can you show us the querie you have tried so far?

Comment: sure, you can `order by` arbitrary/derived values, so `order by previous - current` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users.*, weight_tracking.*
FROM users left join weight_tracking on users.id = weight_tracking.user_id
ORDER BY previous_weight - current_weight desc
```

if a user can have more than one row in weight_tracking table, you could use something like this:

```
SELECT users.*
FROM users left join weight_tracking on users.id = weight_tracking.user_id
GROUP BY users.id
ORDER BY max(previous_weight) - min(current_weight) desc
```

Comment: They can only have one. thank very much your first answer worked it seems.  i am just waiting till i could click the V to accept this answer